# Disable @Async calls in test context

Tags: java, spring, asynchronous, junit, spring-test

I am trying to test void method annotated with @Async. Smth like this:

```
    @Async
    public void asyncMethod()
    {
        //some actions
    }
```

I know that there is an ability to turn off anync execution in tests Not adding @EnableConfig to my test spring configuration file.
The problem is that my test spring configuration class contains .xml configs. And the async call property is enabled in that configs.
This is my test config class:

```
@Configuration
@ImportResource(value = {/some paths to xml contexts})
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "package" })
public class TestApplication
{
    // beans
}
```

And this is how async calls turned on in one of xml configs:

```
<task:annotation-driven executor="parallelUpdateExecutor" scheduler="scheduler" mode="aspectj"/>
```

I am interested, if there is an ability to turn off async calls in test spring context?
Thanks.

Comment: It isn't an option to remove your Asyn from xml to annotion based config?

Comment: No :)) Other tests use it

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way would be to make use of *bean definition profiles*.

You could put the `<task:annotation-driven ...` declaration in a nested `<beans profile="async" ...` section in your XML file and then only activate that profile for tests that need it via `@ActiveProfiles("async")`.

Regards

Sam (*author of the Spring TestContext Framework*)